# getting rid of "figures", "phenomena" and "features" in describing a common trend

Tags: phrase-request

I've noticed that in describing some common trends in English such nouns like "figure", "phenomenon" and "feature" are massively used. Is it possible to avoid using them and yet convey the same thought? For example, is it possible to somehow rephrase the following sentences while retaining the original meaning?

> "The female office worker became a relatively common **figure** only
> in the late 19th century"

> "The female worker at the office became a relatively common **phenomenon** only
> in the late 19th century"

> "Using female workers at the office became a relatively common **feature** only
> in the late 19th century"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop it:

"Female office workers became relatively common only in the late 19th century"

But adding the "phenomenon" or "figure" or "feature" makes it sound more like an "event". The most I can say is that it sounds more professional or formal when you add this word.